# Имя функции из значения переменной C++

Tags: c++

В PHP существует такая фича:

```
$func_name = 'print'
$func_name('test')
```

Можно ли осуществить подобное в C++?

Comment: да есть такое и в С++, называется указатель на функцию.

Comment: Нет, вызова по динамическому имени (то есть по сути рефлексии) в C++ нету. Но вам это и не должно быть нужно, в C++ есть другие выразительные средства.

Comment: Можно `switch` сделать (например скриптом) который по названию будет возвращать ф-ию.

Answer (score 7):

Да есть такое и в С++, есть указатели на функции, смотрите код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int example(const int a, const int b){
    return a * b;
}

typedef // создаем новый прототип (в данном случае указатель на функцию)
        int // возвращаемое значение (такое же как в функциях)
            (*func) // имя прототипа (в коде употребляется без звездочки)
                   (const int, const int); // список параметров (такое же как в функциях)

int main(){
    func test = example;

    cout << test(3, 2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

результат:

[image: result]

Comment: "func test = example;" -- а может ли example быть строкой?

Comment: [Тут пишут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473313/how-to-call-a-function-by-its-name-stdstring-in-c) что нет, но показан вариант как обойти.

Comment: @Alekcvp а вы посмотрите на лучший ответ там используется в коде `typedef int (*FnPtr)(int, int);` - это указатель на функцию

Comment: @FilippMustang нет не может быть строкой для этого случая нужен разбор строки (парсинг)

Comment: @FilippMustang, в определенных случаях можно вызвать и по строке без парсинга... Почитайте [man dlopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) и обратите внимание на `If filename is NULL, then the returned handle is for the main
       program.` (а в винде (Вы же наверное в основном интересуетесь ей?), подозреваю, тоже д.б. нечто подобное)

Comment: @avp, под Windows необходимо указать `__declspec(dllexport)` для тех функций, указатель на которые необходимо получать по имени, чтобы компоновщик занёс их в таблицу экспорта EXE-файла.

Comment: @perfect и что? Вопрос был, как вызвать функцию по её имени в виде строки. Понятно что там будет использоваться указатель, как иначе-то?

Comment: @Alekcvp если внимательно посмотреть на код лучшего ответа то на мой взгляд там делают не нужную вещь я бы весь этот код заменил на обычное ветвление:

`if (s == "add")` 
`test = add;` 
`if (s == "sub")`
`test = sub;`

`test(1, 2); // выполнили функцию`

где `test` - это указатель на функцию, и не пришлось бы прибигать к дорогостоящему выделению памяти

Comment: @perfect, этот спор не имеет смысла, т.к. мы не знаем условий задачи. Например, если там 3-5 таких функций, то да. А если их 50? А если набор доступных функций должен меняться в рантайме в зависимости от каких-то условий?..

Comment: @Alekcvp а вот сейчас вы правильно мыслите, согласен

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример для Linux, как можно искать и вызывать функции по имени
(все подробности в [man dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) и SEE ALSO там)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <gnu/lib-names.h> // Defines LIBM_SO (which will be a string such as "libm.so.6") 

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
double drand ()
{
  return (double)rand();
}

double drand2 (double a)
{
  return  ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) * a;
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  void *hmain = dlopen(0, RTLD_LAZY),
    *hmath = dlopen(LIBM_SO, RTLD_LAZY);

  if (!hmain)
    exit((fprintf(stderr, "dlopen(main): %s\n", dlerror()), 1));
  if (!hmath)
    fprintf(stderr, "dlopen(%s): %s\n", LIBM_SO, dlerror());

  char fname[101];
  double a;
  int rc;

  while ((rc = scanf("%100s %lf", fname, &a)) != EOF) {
    if (rc == 2) {
      double (*f)(double) = (__typeof__(f))dlsym(hmain, fname);
      if (!f && hmath)
        f = (__typeof__(f))dlsym(hmath, fname);
      if (f) 
        printf("%s(%f) = %f\n", fname, a, f(a));
      else 
        fprintf(stderr, "dlsym(%s): %s\n", fname, dlerror());
    } else
      fputs("Invalid input, try again or finish by ^D\n", stderr);
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Условная компиляция, включающая `extern "C" {` нужна для того, чтобы имена функций при использовании крестового (С++, g++) компилятора можно было вводить  в том же виде, как Вы их пишете (а не что-то вроде `_Z5drandv` и `_Z6drand2d`).

Проверял в gcc и g++.

Компилировать нужно с флагами `-ldl` (для подключения библиотеки непосредственно с `dlopen()`, `dlsym()` и т.д.) и `-rdynamic` для того, чтобы имена функций определенных в самом модуле (здесь в файле с `main()`), стали доступны dlsym.

Т.е.
    `gcc fncall.c -ldl -rdynamic   -Wall`
или
    `g++ fncall.c -ldl -rdynamic   -Wall`

Comment: здравствуйте, первое что кидается в глаза это целая куча кода из за банальной задачи, если присмотреться к коду автора вопроса, то все что там происходит то это всего лишь создание псевдонима для нативной функции print, не проще ли создать такой псевдоним за счет дублирующего указателя?

Comment: @perfect, возможно для конкретной задачи еще проще использовать банальный `#define`. Я же показал, что в C/C++, как языке системного программирования, существуют и намного более гибкие средства (реальная динамика), о которых автор м.б. и не подозревал (хотя, из его вопроса, как мне показалось, следует как раз обратное -- подозревал, что что-то такое есть, а вот как это выразить -- не знал).

Comment: да все верно сказали такая задача не имеет применения.

Comment: @perfect, это Вы о вызове функции по ее имени, полученном в ходе работы программы?

Comment: нет я о вопросе автора.